# SuperSocket - Get the full message appServer_NewRequestReceived event

Tags: supersocket.net

How do I get the full message appServer_NewRequestReceived event. For example, if I send a message "0000858 5521113 GT855500" in requestInfo.Key is "0000858" and requestInfo.Body comes "5521113 GT855500". 
I wonder if there is a way where you can get the complete message passed on telnet?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve as follows:

public class MyAppServer : AppServer

```
public class CustomStringParser : IRequestInfoParser<StringRequestInfo>
{
    public StringRequestInfo ParseRequestInfo(string source)
    {
        return new StringRequestInfo("", source, new []{""});
    }
}
```

Thank you all